# Does having multiple work dimensions in a work group/item provides a speedup?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

In OpenCL, does having multiple work dimensions in a work group/item provides a speedup? If so, please point to some code or link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in fact it solws execution down, since the runtime has to perform the local and global id mapping.